# No overwrite -n being ignored by cp command

Tags: linux, macos, bash, shell, unix

I'm trying to `cp` some files on an OSX desktop that fit a pattern of five digits. It works, but I can't understand why the `-n` option is being ignored. I don't want to overwrite a file if it already at the desination.

```
find ./prefix* -name '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]' -maxdepth 5 -exec cp -nr {} ./dest \;
```

Everything is copied, even though one directory is already in `dest`. How can I force no overwrite?  [This solution](https://superuser.com/a/61106/391095) on super user indicates that I could simply change the permissions on everything in `dest` to read only. But I feel like there must be a reason why my implementation `cp` is behaving inconsistent to that which is on the `man` page, and there should therefore be a better way to solve the problem.

Also, the permissions for the file being overwritten are `rwxr-xr-x` (or `0755` if octal is your thing).

Comment: are you sure `-n` applies to directories? the manpage only talks about files.

Comment: @AndreasGrapentin Sigh. Good point.

Comment: @AndreasGrapentin Any ideas on how to make it work with directories?

Comment: unfortunately not, or I would have posted an answer. but maybe you could make it work with rsync? if not, you may have to write a small program in python or something similar, that does exactly what you want.

Comment: I would (or, rather, _do_) go the `rsync` route, myself.

Answer (score 1):

`cp`won't do what you want. You'll need to iterate over the output from `find`. Assuming you don't have spaces or other special characters in any of the paths you find (see below if you do):

```
find ./prefix* -name '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]' -maxdepth 5 | \
while read dir
do
    target=./dest/$(basename $dir)
    [ -d $target ] || cp -r $dir ./dest/
done
```

This works because `while` will keep executing what's between `do` and `done` as long as `read` returns success. The output from `find` is piped into `read` so every time `read dir` executes, it reads one line of output from find and assigns it to the `dir`variable.

When there are no more lines to be read from `find`, `read` returns failure and the loop terminates.

Inside the loop body, `basename` prints the last part of the path passed to it. In this case, the 5 digits.

The `[ ... ]` is shell lingo for running a conditional test. (Yes, `[` is a command!) You could say `test -d ...` instead of `[ -d ... ]`. See e.g. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/99185/what-do-square-brackets-mean-without-the-if-on-the-left for more info on this)

`-d ...` returns success if the argument exists as a directory. Failure if not.

`||` means or - so `foo || bar` executes `bar` only if `foo` fails.

So the loop body basically says:

```
let target be "dest/" + the basename of $dir
such a directory exists or copy $dir into dest/
```

I hope that clarifies it a bit. It's a lot of shell lingo in very little code. All of this is information basically in the `bash` manpage, though arguably in a much less accessible format.

If there's any chance that any of the paths found by `find` contain spaces or other special characters, then you'll need to add quoting and a few other bells & whistles:

```
find ./prefix* -name '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]' -maxdepth 5 -print0 | \
while IFS= read -r -d '' dir
do
    target="./dest/$(basename "$dir")"
    [ -d "$target" ] || cp -r "$dir" ./dest/
done
```

Comment: Explained and elaborated. Hope it helps.

Comment: This doesn't work with all valid UNIX filenames as given. `read` needs `-r` to deal with filenames with backslashes, `IFS` needs to be cleared to handle filenames ending in whitespace, and filenames with newlines can't be handled at all while the stream is line-oriented.

Comment: Even better -- handling all the corner cases -- would be to use the `-print0` action in `find`, and `while IFS= read -r -d '' dir` on the bash side.

Comment: Also, there are a bunch of quoting bugs. `[ -d $target ]` needs to be `[ -d "$target" ]`, for instance; `target=dest/$(basename $dir)` needs to be `target=dest/$(basename "$dir")` (or `target=dest/${dir%/*}`, which is considerably more efficient); etc.

Comment: ...the above aren't exploitable via filenames here since those names are restricted by the `find` expression, but (1) answers given in StackOverflow get reused by other people with different use cases and constraints; and (2) they *are* exploitable by _directory_ names, when those directories contain matching files.

Comment: Added a properly quoted version.